# Custom Listview not showing untill Edittext is selected and Keyboard comes up

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-edittext

So i am having a very strange problem, i have an activity that shows user's posts and date in a ListView with a Custom ListView, gets from the server and populates them on **onCreate**.

***this is how the interface looks of the activity***[image]

***so what's happening is whenever i start the activity the edittext part was getting selected and generally the keyboard comes up***

i googled to how to not **focus the EditText** at startup 
found by adding these two lines in the parent layout focus on the EditText can be prevented

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

so i added that to the RelativeLayout xml of the activity this is the xml of the picture above

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/verticalLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".UserHome">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tweetText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="122dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Write Your Tweet"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/userListHome"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="postTweetFunction"
        android:text="Post" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userListHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tweetText"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Now about the problem part i needed to say above to make you understand what is the problem exactly cause its a strange one.**

***so the listview is not appearing until the editext is selected and  the keyboard comes up***

***i am sure the listview is populating and the custom listview is working***

***but the listview content does not appear until i select the editext and the keyboard comes up, like the listview was sleeping until the editext is selected.***

**here is the example**
[image]

***see in that activity and the editext is not selected, so even thou the listview is populated it's not showing.***

**but as soon as i click on he edittext and the keyboard comes up its like it wokes up the sleeping listview**
[image]
[image]

**and the listview and adapter is not anonymous i have defined them**
here is the activity code if needed for reference

```
public class UserHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> userOwnTweets;
    ArrayList<String> userOwnTweetsDate;
    ArrayList<String> getUserOwnTweetsObjectId;
    EditText tweetText;
    CustomArrayAdapter customArrayAdapter;
    Typeface custom_font1, custom_font2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_home);

        custom_font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/gooddog.otf");
        custom_font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),  "fonts/quicksand.otf");

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userListHome);
        tweetText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tweetText);

        userOwnTweets = new ArrayList<String>();
        userOwnTweetsDate = new ArrayList<String>();
        getUserOwnTweetsObjectId = new ArrayList<String>();


        customArrayAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext());
        listView.setAdapter(customArrayAdapter);


        // updating the tweets onCreate
        updateTweetList();

    }


    public void updateTweetList(){

        // clearing the lists to avoid duplicate entries
        userOwnTweets.clear();
        userOwnTweetsDate.clear();
        getUserOwnTweetsObjectId.clear();



        // just backend code to get the tweets of the user
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Tweet");
        query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null && objects.size() > 0){

                    for (ParseObject object : objects){

                        String tempString = object.getString("tweet");
                        tempString = tempString.substring(0, Math.min(tempString.length(), 20));
                        tempString+="...";

                        // adding them to the arraylists
                        userOwnTweets.add(tempString);
                        userOwnTweetsDate.add(object.getString("date"));
                        getUserOwnTweetsObjectId.add(object.getObjectId());
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // updating the customlistview for datastatechanged
        customArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void postTweetFunction(View view){



        // adding a new tweet and refreshing the tweet list from teh server
        ParseObject userTwitter = new ParseObject("Tweet");
        userTwitter.put("tweet", tweetText.getText().toString());
        userTwitter.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
        userTwitter.put("date", String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(new Date())));
        userTwitter.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {

                if (e == null) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tweet Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tweetText.setText("");
                    updateTweetList();

                }
            }
        });
        hideKeyBoard();


    }

    public void hideKeyBoard(){


        // hiding the keyboard
        try {
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // the custom adapter
    class CustomArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        // Constructor
        public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return userOwnTweets.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return userOwnTweets.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

            TextView userHomeTweet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userHomeTweet);
            TextView userHomeTweetdate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userHomeTweetDate);
            userHomeTweet.setTypeface(custom_font1);
            userHomeTweetdate.setTypeface(custom_font2);

            try {
                userHomeTweet.setText(userOwnTweets.get(i));
                userHomeTweetdate.setText(userOwnTweetsDate.get(i));
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // random color for each

            int color = Color.LTGRAY;
            view.setBackgroundColor(color);

            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

***i have used proper commenting, the code is simple enough , i am just using a Server with MongoDB i have commented on them.***

and this is the customlistview layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userHomeTweet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userHomeTweetDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

each of the listview element has a each this layout inside them hence making it  a customlistview

SO here is everything i am as clear as possible, but ask me if i missed anything that may make a difference in solving the issue

**so can you tell me, why the listview does not show up until i select the EditText and the Keyboard comes up, seems like a strange problem, please point me in the right direction. Thanks.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/verticalLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:context=".UserHome">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tweetText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Write Your Tweet"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/userListHome"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="postTweetFunction"
        android:text="Post" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/userListHome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tweetText"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT**

```
public void updateTweetList(){

        // clearing the lists to avoid duplicate entries
        userOwnTweets.clear();
        userOwnTweetsDate.clear();
        getUserOwnTweetsObjectId.clear();



        // just backend code to get the tweets of the user
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Tweet");
        query.whereEqualTo("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

                if (e == null && objects.size() > 0){

                    for (ParseObject object : objects){

                        String tempString = object.getString("tweet");
                        tempString = tempString.substring(0, Math.min(tempString.length(), 20));
                        tempString+="...";

                        // adding them to the arraylists
                        userOwnTweets.add(tempString);
                        userOwnTweetsDate.add(object.getString("date"));
                        getUserOwnTweetsObjectId.add(object.getObjectId());
                    }

                   // updating the customlistview for datastatechanged
                   customArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: here is the screenshot after modifying with your code

Comment: yes working flawlessly, so i needed to update the custom-adapter inside the query completion, for some reason the 

customArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); was not reaching.